# Display rowIndex for dropdown in each row of the table

Tags: jquery, row

I am trying to echo the rowIndex of the row in a table, when the dropdown (in td tags) in that row changes and its options (selectdevice is the class for the dropdowns). Currently i am getting undefined being displayed:

```
$('#tabletomodify').on('change','.selectdevice', function () {
  alert( this.parentNode.rowIndex );
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  var valueSelected = this.value;                               
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem likely is `this` is the `select` element, so the `this.parentNode` will be the `td` element not the `tr` element which has the [rowIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex) property. In this case you need to locate the `tr` element to which the `select` belongs to.

So assuming the `select` is a direct child of the `td` element you can try to access the parent's(td) parent element.

```
alert( this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dn4LH/)

or using jQuery you can find the parent `tr` element using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
alert( $(this).closest('tr').prop('rowIndex') );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L8ka9/)